# Iphone graphice design

Tags: iphone

I designed buttons are not clear in corners in my app in iphone, what is the photoshop resolution for designing Iphone icons and other navigation icons?

Answer (score 2):

Here you'll find all the information you need: [Apple documentation on creating icons and other artwork](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1)

Answer (score 2):

Use the 300 resolution when you are doing the Photoshop design.

Answer (score 1):

The specific resolution isn't actually what they're looking at. What matters is the number of pixels in the document.  so 1" x 1" @ 100 is the same as 2" x 2" @ 50

Also here are some great scripts for exporting assets ready for iPhone use.

https://github.com/sponno/iPhone-Photoshop-JSX-Icon-Exporter